# Joomla template for non Joomla website

Tags: css, templates, joomla, joomla-template

A Joomla website has been rebuilt to a non Joomla website. The client would prefer to keep the look and feel of the website and I am considering of reusing the Joomla template. Is it possible to use a Joomla template in a non Joomla website? If so, why do templates for Joomla at [Themeforest](http://themeforest.net/) fall under the category CMS? What is the difference between a Joomla template and an HTML template?

Comment: The joomla templates are basically html templates but they have php code and placeholders like `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-0" style="none" />`, to help place content, these have no meaning in a non-joomla framework so you would get errors and such. You would have to replace the code and remove the placeholders and insert your own code for use with your framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: no.

The long answer: Joomla templates make use of Joomla framework facilities to calculate and format their layouts. It might be possible to refactor a Joomla template if you seek out all the references to Joomla code and create some way of providing that functionality. It would probably be easier to create the HTML layout from scratch, modelling it on the style of the Joomla original.

Comment: To get the HTML, just "save as" in the browser, get the html and remove the dynamic content, it's a long work but it's still better than starting from scratch.